# N2O production vs air distillation

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, distillation

After producing nitrogen by distilling air, how is that nitrogen used with the oxygen to yield nitrous oxide ($\ce{N2O}$)? I see $\ce{N2O}$ available in different purities from various suppliers, but how is that different from just distilling air? When distilling nitrogen from air, once both gasses have reached the right temp/pressure to become a liquid, what is preventing it from becoming $\ce{N2O}$ in a liquid form instead of one floating on top of the other? These questions are in reference to an automotive application.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Just so we're clear here, liquid air is a physical mixture, a solution composed mostly of dinitrogen ($\ce{N2}$), dioxygen ($\ce{O2}$) and argon ($\ce{Ar}$). There are almost no nitrous oxide molecules. In principle you could take $\ce{N2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ and react them (combustion) to produce $\ce{N2O}$, but this process would be quite difficult to control, as there are several more stable nitrogen oxides. This probably precludes usage of nitrogen combustion in oxygen as a source of large amounts of nitrous oxide.

Answer (score 4):

> After producing nitrogen by distilling air, how is that nitrogen used with the oxygen to yield nitrous oxide ($\ce{N2O}$)?

It's not clear to me that $\ce{N2O}$ is produced from $\ce{N2}$: Rather, it appears that commercial quantities of $\ce{N2O}$ are produced by thermally decomposing ammonium nitrate:
$$\ce{NH4NO3(s) -> N2O(g) + 2H2O(g)}$$
as described (at least) by [this manufacturer and supplier of nitrous oxide gas plants](http://www.nitrousoxidegasplants.com/manufacturing-process.html). See the [comprehensive Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrous_oxide#Production) for more information.

> I see $\ce{N2O}$ available in different purities from various suppliers, but how is that different from just distilling air?

I'm not sure what you mean here.

> When distilling nitrogen from air, once both gasses have reached the right temp/pressure to become a liquid, what is preventing it from becoming $\ce{N2O}$ in a liquid form instead of one floating on top of the other?

Nitrogen is liquid in the range [63 to 77 K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen); for oxygen, it's [54 to 90 K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen). Thus, the temperature range for which both are liquids is bounded by the range on nitrogen, or roughly between 63 and 77 K.

The temperature at which nitrous oxide solidifies (182 K per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrous_oxide)) is much higher than the temperature range at which oxygen and nitrogen are in the liquid phase, and thus it would have come out of solution as a solid long before the requisite temperature was reached. Thus, we would not expect to see liquid $\ce{N2O}$ co-existing with liquid oxygen and nitrogen.

Note bene: I am using the pressure range of 5 to 10 bars as cited [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_separation) in assuming that liquid and solid phases of the above moieties do not coexist during industrial gas production at these relatively low pressures.